# Finding domain of function and writing in interval notation

Tags: functions, notation

I think I have the answer but it always takes me a long time to find it and wanted to check it.  Equation is;$$ f(x) =\frac{\sqrt {x+4}}{x-4}$$ Interval notation then is $$ [-4, 4) \cup (4, \infty)$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sqrt{x+4}$ yields $x\ge -4$ and $\frac{1}{x-4}$ yields $x\ne 4$, so $x$ can be anything greater than $-4$ excluding $4$. Therefore we can write $x \in [-4,+\infty) \setminus \{ 4\}$ or equivalently $x \in [-4,4)\cup (4, +\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks for the additional notation.  I will have to look up the set builder notation.  I think that is part of your answer.  When do you ever use set builder notation?  I have only had to answer questions with interval notation.  Also thanks for taking the numerator and putting it into an inequality. Also the denominator cannot be zero.  I forgot how to show those or that I could do it that way.  thanks.